# Can we install Bandicam on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, screen, screenshot

I tried to install Bandicam on ubuntu 22.04, but there was non installation provided on official website,only on windows, so is there a way to install Bandicam on ubuntu/linux?

Comment: Screen recording is part of gnome in Ubuntu 22.04. Windows apps generally don't work on Ubuntu. See [How to Record Screen on Ubuntu 22.04?](https://itslinuxfoss.com/record-screen-ubuntu-22-04/) for more.